# How to maintain request data for all request?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

---

First i am sending request and get the response values(I am not returning the response values to the ui)i want the response values should keep in java.
Then i send another request this time i want the first response values(That have been kept in java)? 
I have tried with static Map, but what is the problem is I got duplicate values so the Map eliminate those values.Please help me to achieve this scenario.is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Show the code you've done so far.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give advice based on such vague goals, but the approach you have specified lacks durability and will be difficult to scale.  If that JVM goes down, you will lose all of the data that it is storing.  Instead, you might want to look into a full-fledged dbms and/or something like memcached, if you're really concerned about keeping the data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Using a static map should be able to resolve your problem provided you mantain a unique key. You may have to implement a concept of requestId as well. Generate a unique requestId for each incoming request and put the response object against it. You can use [Java UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) to generate a unique requestId.